# Can I have this script above my content?

Tags: javascript, html

Example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html

I wish to incorporate the above script into my one home page I am designing.  These will have links, buttons and other content etc. The only problem is I can't seem to get the birds to be above my main content/website. Is there a proper way to present the code in order to have them showing above everything else? Thanks for any and all input!

Edit:

How can I get the birds to show above my actual website so users can see. I have been experimenting with it and every time I bring my website in, or the code in, the birds are behind my actual website and cant be seen. Hope that makes things clearer! Thank you!

Comment: "Showing above everything else?" What do you mean?

Comment: Showing above my actual website so users can see.  I have been experimenting with it and every time I bring my website in, or the code in, the birds are behind my actual website and cant be seen.  Hope that makes things clearer! Thank you!

Comment: Just set z-index. Like <div id="birds" style="z-index:3;"> But then how will the user see your actual site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everything is rendered to the container div.

So try replacing this

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

With this

```
<div id="container" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Alternativly you can insert the container div in the area you want the header to be and it should fit to that space?

**EDIT!!**

I think I mistook your question?  use z-index in the container div

```
<div id="container" style="z-index: 99;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, don't use Three.js for the birds because some older browsers don't support it. Why not just make a GIF of your birds? Or make several DIVs with bird pics and move them around.